# using two .NET 1.1 web services getting server application unavailable with one, other one works

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, .net-1.1

I have a .NET framework 1.1 application that uses two web services, one handles security and the other business functionality. Both were working fine. I made a change to the service responsible for business functionality, as well as the main application, and reinstalled both the web service and the main application. I have done this at least twice before, but this time, after logging in (which shows that the security web service is working), any access to the biz web service fails with "Server Application Unavailable. The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable."

There is no error logged in the event application log.

It works fine on my development laptop (in the Visual Studio .NET 2003 dev environment), this error only occurs when I install it on the server (Windows Server 2003 Standard).

I'm really stumped because all I changed was some code affecting functionality, and I built the application in exactly the same was as the last time.

Comment: Both services are in the same app pool, and there is no other app using a different .NET version. When I navigate to the asmx file of the security web service in a browser it lists the operations, but when I navigate to any of the asmx files in the business web service I get the server application unavailable error. I've checked that the two folders have the same permissions.

Comment: I've resolved the issue. The problem was the asmx files in the biz web service were all pointed to the tempuri URI. I discovered this on my development laptop when I browsed to the asmx files in a browser. After defining a permanent URI in the asmx files (e.g. [WebService(Namespace="http://tmm-web.com/bizrules/")]), I rebuilt and reinstalled on the server and I was able to successfully navigate the asmx page on the server.

Comment: you should make the above comment the answer